# Javascript if/else statements help, what am i doing wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, variables

The following code is from my course and I can't get it to work.

I've tried putting everything possible that i can think of

```js
var eatSteak = confirm("Do you eat steak?");
var confirmSteak = confirm("You like Steak!");
var confirmNoSteak = confirm("Here's a tofu stir-fry");
var howOld = prompt("How old are you?");
var howNotOld = confirm("No Sake for you!");
var sakeForYou = confirm("Sake for you!");
var tryAgain = confirm("TRY AGAIN!");
if (eatSteak == true) {
  alert(confirmSteak);
} else {
  alert(confirmNoSteak);
}
if (howOld < 21) {
  alert(howNotOld);
} else if (howOld >= 21) {
  alert(sakeForYou);
} else {
  alert(tryAgain);
}
```

No error messages displayed by console

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: use return false

Comment: Did you write the function called "confirm"?  It seems like that is what is missing from the code ...

Answer (score 1):

`confirm()` should only be used to ask a question. If you just want to set a variable to a message, you shouldn't call `confirm()`. So statements like

```
var confirmSteak = confirm("You like Steak!");
```

should just be

```
var confirmSteak = "You like Steak!";
```

Also, when you're testing `howOld`, you check if they're less than 21, then check if they're at least 21. Those are the only two possibilities, it can never get to the last `else` block. So you can just use `if` and `else` -- either they get sake or not.

```js
var eatSteak = confirm("Do you eat steak?");
var confirmSteak = "You like Steak!";
var confirmNoSteak = "Here's a tofu stir-fry";
var howOld = prompt("How old are you?");
var howNotOld = "No Sake for you!";
var sakeForYou = "Sake for you!";
if (eatSteak == true) {
  alert(confirmSteak);
} else {
  alert(confirmNoSteak);
}
if (howOld < 21) {
  alert(howNotOld);
} else  {
  alert(sakeForYou);
}
```

Comment: ah ok! i see thank you! i see that i am taking the longer route by storing all the vars but I ultimately just wanted to make it user friendly if i was to pass it along to someone else. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

One simple rule. Use `prompt` and `confirm` only when you want to get a user input.

```js
if (confirm("Do you eat steak?") == true) 
   alert('You like Steak!')
else 
   alert('Heres a tofu stir-fry');



//Here is a variable which stores the user input
var age = prompt("How old are you?");

if (age < 21)
  alert('No Sake for you!')  
else 
  if (age > 21) 
    alert('Sake for you!')  
  else 
    alert('TRY AGAIN!');
```

Comment: wow thanks alot, i see that i made it longer by storing more vars rather than using strings as an output in my if/else statements!